# Does upgrading to SVN 1.7 on local require an upgrade on the repository?

Tags: svn, upgrade

I have updated to the latest of SVN on my Windows 7 to 1.7. When I went to my working copy, it requires me to upgrade the working copy to 1.7 format to be able to work. There's no other options. But I'm afraid that if I do upgrade, the version of local working copy and the version of the repository on the server are different and there may appear the inconsistent format error or something like that. I don't want to risk the code changes on local. Should I upgrade to format 1.7 or not? Is there solution for me to go back to previous?

Comment: that was really, really clearly stated in the release notes https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html What you might want to know is that nested svn:externals do not work anymore.

Comment: sorry I also downvoted but that wasn't meant. Should you edit your question I'll cancel my downvote!

Answer (score 7):

No, the repository need not be updated but the working copy will have to be updated.

Upgrading the working copy means, older clients cannot use the working copy, but you can work with older servers / repos using the newer working copy / client

Answer (score 1):

No, you can leave the repository alone: https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like uberSVN you can toggle between 1.6 and 1.7.